# Swift troubleshooting, display data in a Xcode playground?

Tags: swift

I'm really new with programming and have started with Swift. I do not really now how to express myself since I don't really know what I'm doing...

I want to display the message from the `println(" number ")`. I'm trying to write a playground that tells me which 10th number my number closest to. 
So I would like something like this:

```
if a > 10 && a < 15 {
    println("10") // <- I want this presented at the top of the code.
}
```

This is a general question how to display data somewhere else.

Is this even possible through a playground?

I am currently getting the results from the if-statements in the assistant editor where the code is executed, but I want to have it where the variable "a" is defined.

All of the playground is presented below.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import UIKit   
var a = 5
// I want to present the answer here !    
if a < 5 {
    println("0")
}
else if a > 5 && a < 10 {
    println("10")
}
else if a > 10 && a < 15 {
    println("10")
}
else if a > 15 && a <= 20 {
    println("20")
}
else if a > 20 && a < 25 {
    println("20")
}
else if a > 25 && a <= 30 {
    println("30")
}
else if a > 30 && a < 35 {
    println("30")
}
else if a > 35 && a <= 40 {
    println("40")
}
else if a > 40 && a < 45 {
    println("40")
}
else if a > 45 && a <= 50 {
    println("50")
}
else {
    print("In between")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you not seeing the results printed? Sounds like you may not have the Assistant Editor open. To open the assistant editor to go *View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor*. You should get a box titled "Console Output" displaying your results.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yes I have it open, I wonder if it is possible to print the result up where I put in the value of the variable "a". Or is this not possible in playground?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand. Are you looking to print the value of `a` or just the result that you get from the `if` statements? Perhaps you could edit your question to add what your currently getting outputted and what you would like to have?

Comment: Yes exactly, the result from the if statements.

Comment: That's just a preview, it doesn't look like the assistant editor is open from the screenshot (unless it's off the screen to the right).